# Old Norse Weak Adjectives

Tags: germanic-languages, old-norse

In Old Norse, the weak plural forms of adjectives is "-u"(except for dative). This is the case in all genders, like how Common West Germanic forms seem to be "*-ōn".

What are the sound changes that led to this ending?

Comment: Given that the weak inflection generally followed the _n_-stems in Proto-Germanic and had a mixture of _*-īn-_ and _*-ōn-_ in the plural, I don’t think sound changes alone can explain the Old Norse forms. Inherently weak adjectives like _fleiri_ have plural forms in _-i_ rather than _-u_, which seems more like a reasonable outcome, but the productive weak inflection pattern is, I think, more down to analogy than sound change.